# insert row and if exists increment by 1

Tags: mysql

My table beers is made by:
userid, tohave
I use this:

```
INSERT INTO beers (userid,tohave) VALUES (1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tohave=VALUES (tohave)
```

Is fine because the userid value (userid is PRIMARY) exists just updates the row but in my case if userid exists I want to add 1 to column tohave.
Is it possible doing it with one query?

Comment: Man just look at docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html it's first example.

Answer (score 2):

Add +1?

```
INSERT INTO beers (userid,tohave) 
VALUES (1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE tohave = VALUES(tohave) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works this way: INSERT INTO beers (userid,tohave) VALUES (3,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tohave=tohave +1.  VALUES(tohave +1) gives error

Comment: UPDATE tohave=VALUES (tohave + 1) --> UPDATE tohave=VALUES (tohave) + 1